# return rows with unique values in two columns, not just unique rows

Tags: t-sql, aggregation, counting

I have a situation akin to an order table and an invoice table. The link between them should be 1:1 however, due to systemic error, the order numbers for some invoices get lost. This causes me pain and aguish.

I need to make best guesses as to which order numbers belong to the orphaned invoices.

Most of the matching methods are straightforward and reduce the problem significantly allowing more computationally expensive methods to work on the remainder.
Each method will throw out a small number of duplicates because the method was not unambiguously able to generate a match

I need to build a list of keys in two columns that are unique in the context of each column - not just unique rows - instances where a value duplicates in any column are the ones that need acting on.

| ORD | INV |
| --- | --- |
| 222 | 333 |
| 222 | 444 |
| 444 | 555 |
| 444 | 333 |
| 111 | 333 |
| 888 | 777 |

only

| ORD | INV |
| --- | --- |
| 888 | 777 |

should be returned.

I've tried a few ways of counting but I've not had any success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a (non-selected) aggregation with a `having` condition limiting the count to 1 for each column

```
select A, B
from mytable
where A in (select A from mytable group by A having count(*) = 1)
and B in (select B from mytable group by B having count(*) = 1)
```

Comment: I used this version, it fixed the problem with the least lines. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's possible to create list of values you want (example for column B values):

```
select B
from SourceTable
group by B
having count(*) = 1
```

and just use inner join with source table

```
select T.A, T.B
from SourceTable T
join (
  select A
  from SourceTable 
  group by A
  having count(*) = 1
) ADist ON T.A = ADist.A
join (
  select B
  from SourceTable
  group by B
  having count(*) = 1
) BDist ON T.B = BDist.B
```

Here is [example on fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/fc8301/3/0)